# error: 'ballPosition' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, raylib

I'm getting this problem where I get this error message;

```
error: 'ballPosition' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

This is my code

```
#include"raylib.h"

int main()
{
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth,screenHeight, "ArcadeGame");
    
    while(!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        ballPosition = GetMousePosition();
        BeginDrawing();
            DrawCircleV(ballPosition, 35, DARKBLUE);
             ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
             
        EndDrawing();
    }
    
    CloseWindow();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to look at some examples but it still wont work.

Comment: Where *is* the variable `ballPosition` declared or defined?

Comment: You need to declare `ballPosition`. You need to write the type of `ballPosition` before the first use of it, just like you did with `screenWidth`. What type does `GetMousePosition()` return?

Comment: That's very basic C knowledge and it's explained on the first pages of virtually all C text books.

Comment: @BreadDevelopers What is unclear with the error message?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's unclear if you have only been exposed to dynamically typed languages like Python or Javascript.

Comment: If you truly don't understand why you get the error message, or what *declarations* and *definitions* are, then you need to take quite a few steps back, and start with a true beginners book or tutorial, which will teach you the very basics of C.

Answer (score 1):

In C, every variable needs a defined type. When you declare or define a new variable, you have to give a type (there are some exceptions where `int` is used without a type given but that isn't relevant for now). You didn't specify a type for `ballPosition`, so the compiler doesn't know the type and and complains.

When you look at the source code of [`raylib.h`](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raylib.h), you see that `GetMousePosition()` returns a `Vector2`-type value, `Vector2` is a `struct` and `typedef` defined in [`raylib.h`](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raylib.h). Therefore it makes sense to `Vector2` as type for `ballPosition`.
You can do that by writing the type `Vector2` before `ballPosition` is used the first time in a scope;

Answer (score 1):

The C programming language is a so called *statically typed* language with explicitly typed variable declarations. This means that every variable has a fixed type which must be specified in a variable declaration. In this case we can see at line 1129 in https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raylib.h that the function *GetMousePosition* is declared as

```
RLAPI Vector2 GetMousePosition(void);  // Get mouse position XY
```

so it returns a value of type *Vector2*. Therefor you need to declare the variable *ballPosition* with this type:

```
#include"raylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;
    Vector2 ballPosition;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "ArcadeGame");
    while (! WindowShouldClose()) {
        ballPosition = GetMousePosition();
        BeginDrawing();
        DrawCircleV(ballPosition, 35, DARKBLUE);
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```